# Oscurart Add Ons

Tags: add-on

In Blender 4.0 there are no **Oscurart add-ons**, so any alternate tool for this?

Actually, I want to distribute equal features in Blender.

I hope I’ll get a positive response.

Comment: It looks from [this](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/98720) post as if that addon was removed from Blender from version 3.2. The GitHub site where it was available was last updated over 2 years ago and I think from other earlier comments that the author has abandoned it. You could probably do what you want using Geometry nodes but you'll have to explain exactly what you want to do, preferably with images before anyone can help you.

Comment: Since not everybody is familiar with Oscurart addons, it might be helpful to explain what they were capable of to get any recommendation for an alternative.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I agree! I was about to post that it was a third-party addon that most folks would have never heard of and therefore off-topic until I looked it up online! The Blender Manual entry from version 3.0 is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/addons/object/oscurart_tools.html#oscurart-tools) in case anyone wants to see what it did although the descriptions there are somewhat incomplete!

Comment: @JohnEason I actually did not mention "third-party" because I realized from your comment that it was once in there - but since I never saw any tutorial on any topic no matter if texturing, sculpting, simulation, animation, geonodes etc. ever mentioning this addon, I suspected it was one of the lesser known and now that it's no longer in Blender for quite a few versions, it would require first of all people who still have this and secondly maybe not only have it but also be familiar with it. Just a few notes on what specific features he is missing might give quick solutions.

Comment: Just looked in the manual entry and found that some tools there can be achieved in other ways and many of them have "Todo" there, so nice list of tools but actually many of them no explanations available so who knows what they exactly did - I'm not even sure if "Todo" in these cases means the explanation is to do or the functionality itself...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann He mentions "distribute equal feature" which is in the Blender manual and why I mentioned Geometry nodes as I imagine you could do that with them although I agree that there's not much detail in the manual.

Comment: @JohnEason There is _Distribute Objects_ in the manual, I'm not sure if this is meant with "distribute equal features" or what this should mean anyway.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I left it to "those who do know" to work that one out... (I don't!)